# Program to construct house with bricks with 3 dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have 2 classes : 1 brick and 1 construction class, I must built a house or an object with bricks, each construction can take a brick as an argument, it has also operators + , -  and ^ , and +=, -= , ^= , that add a construction on the right of the construction, "behind" (in the depth and 1 level above a construction...
I have to do this with the appropriate according indices of my 3 dimensional vector....

The problem is: Everything compiles fine, but my program crashes when I start this... I spent a whole day on this program and I dont know where my error is...

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    // Pour simplifier
    typedef string Forme   ;
    typedef string Couleur ;

    class Brique
    {
    private:
      Forme   forme   ;
      Couleur couleur ;

    public:
      /*****************************************************
        Compléter le code à partir d'ici
      *******************************************************/
    Brique( Forme f, Couleur c ) : forme(f),couleur(c) {};
    ostream& afficher(ostream& sortie) const ;
    Forme getForme() const {return forme;};
    Couleur getCouleur() const {return couleur;};
    };

    ostream& Brique::afficher(ostream & sortie) const {
    if (this->getCouleur() != "") {
        return sortie<<"("<<this->getForme()<<", "<<this->getCouleur()<<")";
    }
    else {
        return sortie<<this->getForme();
    }
    };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& sortie, Brique const& z) {
        return z.afficher(sortie);
    };


    class Construction
    {
        friend class Grader;
        public:
        vector<vector<vector<Brique> > > contenu;
        public:
        Construction(Brique  b) : contenu(1, vector<vector<Brique> >(1, vector<Brique>(1,b))) {};
        //Construction(Construction  c) ;
        ostream& afficher(ostream& sortie) const ;
        Construction& operator^=(Construction const & z) ;
        Construction& operator-=(Construction const & z) ;
        Construction& operator+=(Construction const & z) ;
    };

    ostream& Construction::afficher(ostream& sortie) const {
        size_t i(contenu.size());
        for (size_t j = 0; j< i; j++) {
        cout<<"Couche "<<j<<" :"<<endl;
        for (size_t k = 0; k<contenu[j].size() ; k++) {
            for (size_t t = 0; t< contenu[j][k].size(); t++) {
                cout <<contenu[j][k][t];
            }
        }
    }
        return cout;
    };


    ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Construction const& z) {
        return z.afficher(o);
    };


    Construction& Construction::operator^=(Construction const & z) {
        //int i(this->contenu.size());
        //int j(this->contenu[i].size());
        //int k(this->contenu[i][j].size());
        int m(z.contenu.size());
        //int n(z.contenu[m].size());
        //int p(z.contenu[m][n].size());
        this->contenu.push_back(z.contenu[m]);
        return *this;
    };

    Construction& operator^(Construction & o, Construction & z) {
        //o.contenu.push_back(z.contenu[z.contenu.size()]);
        o^= z;
        return o;
    }

    Construction& Construction::operator+=(Construction const & z) {
        int i(this->contenu.size());
        int j(this->contenu[i].size());
        //int k(this->contenu[i][j].size());
        int m(z.contenu.size());
        int n(z.contenu[m].size());
        //int p(z.contenu[m][n].size());
        if ( n < j) { return *this;}
        else if ( n > j) {
            int a(0);
            for (auto element : z.contenu[m][n]) {
                this->contenu[i][j].push_back(element); 
                ++a; 
                if (a == n) { return * this;}
            }
        }
        else {
        this->contenu[i].push_back(z.contenu[m][n]);
    }
    return *this;
    }

    Construction operator+(Construction  t, Construction  z) {
        return t+=z;
    }

    Construction& Construction::operator-=(Construction const & z) {
        int i(this->contenu.size());
        int j(this->contenu[i].size());
        int k(this->contenu[i][j].size());
        int m(z.contenu.size());
        int n(z.contenu[m].size());
        int p(z.contenu[m][n].size());
        if ( p < k) { return *this;}
        else  {
        this->contenu[i][j].push_back(z.contenu[m][n][p]);
    }
    return *this;
    }

Construction& operator-(Construction & o, Construction const & z) {
    /*
    int i(o.contenu.size());
    int m(z.contenu.size());
    int n(z.contenu[m].size());
    int p(z.contenu[m][n].size());
    o.contenu[i][m].push_back(z.contenu[m][n][p]);
     */
    return o-=z;
}

const Construction operator*(unsigned int n, Construction const& a)
{

    Construction b = a;
    for (unsigned int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    b.operator+=(a);
    }
    return b;
};


const Construction operator/(unsigned int n, Construction const& a)
{

    Construction b=a;
    for (unsigned int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    b^=a;
    }
    return b;

};

const Construction operator%(unsigned int n, Construction const& a)
{
    Construction b=a;
    for (unsigned int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    b-=a;
    }
    return b;
};

/*******************************************
 * Ne rien modifier après cette ligne.
 *******************************************/

int main()
{
  // Modèles de briques
  Brique toitD("obliqueD", "rouge");
  Brique toitG("obliqueG", "rouge");
  Brique toitM(" pleine ", "rouge");
  Brique mur  (" pleine ", "blanc");
  Brique vide ("                 ", "");

  unsigned int largeur(4);
  unsigned int profondeur(3);
  unsigned int hauteur(3); // sans le toit


  // on construit les murs
  Construction maison( hauteur / ( profondeur % (largeur * mur) ) );

  cout<<maison;

  // on construit le toit
  Construction toit(profondeur % ( toitG + 2*toitM + toitD ));
  toit ^= profondeur % (vide + toitG + toitD);

  // on pose le toit sur les murs
  maison ^= toit;

  // on admire notre construction
  cout << maison << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

anybody got an Idea why my program crashes?

Comment: Well, have you run the program in the debugger to see where it crashes?

Comment: That is a lot of code to expect us to parse through. You can help us if you can compile with debugging symbols on, and then run with a debugger, which will show you the line where things crash. Otherwise, you must provide a very minimal example that still compiles and produces your crash.